# Docker run cant find google authentication "oauth2google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials"

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform

Hey there I am trying to figure out why i keep getting this error when running the docker run command. Here is what i am running

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:2575:2575 -v ~/.config:/home/.config gcr.io/cloud-healthcare-containers/mllp-adapter /usr/mllp_adapter/mllp_adapter --hl7_v2_project_id=****** --hl7_v2_location_id=us-east1 --hl7_v2_dataset_id=*****--hl7_v2_store_id=*****--export_stats=false --receiver_ip=0.0.0.0
```

I have tried both ubuntu and windows with an error that it failed to connect and to see googles service authentication documentation. I have confirmed the account is active and the keys are exported to the config below

```
randon@ubuntu-VM:~/Downloads$ gcloud auth configure-docker
WARNING: Your config file at [/home/brandon/.docker/config.json] contains these credential helper entries:

{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
```

I am thinking its something to do with the -v command on how it uses the google authentication. Any help or guidance to fix, Thank you

```
-v ~/.config:/root/.config is used to give the container access to gcloud credentials;
```

Comment: I can direct you to a link that may be of help[1], however I may need to know more about the configuration.

As well, could you provide the whole error message, (I would like to know if you are receiving this message) : 

“healthapiclient.NewHL7V2Client: oauth2google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials”

[1] could not find default credentials error when running locally : 
https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#could_not_find_default_credentials_error_when_running_locally

Comment: Hi @Amit, Below is the error in my ubuntu machine. yes that is the same error I see and have tried all possible resolution from google help page they point to.

E0829 17:05:24.485902       1 mllp_adapter.go:58] failed to connect to HL7v2 API: oauth2google.DefaultTokenSource: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
brandon@ubuntu-VM:~/Downloads$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same for hours and I decided check the source code even I not being a go developer.

So, there I figured out the we have a [credentials option](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mllp/blob/64dc80dddb642cb290a155c03e3b44d3a3a3ee14/mllp_adapter/mllp_adapter.go#L49) to set the credentials file. It's not documented for now.

The docker command should be like:

```
docker run \
    --network=host \
    -v ~/.config:/root/.config \
    gcr.io/cloud-healthcare-containers/mllp-adapter \
    /usr/mllp_adapter/mllp_adapter \
    --hl7_v2_project_id=$PROJECT_ID \
    --hl7_v2_location_id=$LOCATION \
    --hl7_v2_dataset_id=$DATASET_ID \
    --hl7_v2_store_id=$HL7V2_STORE_ID \
    --credentials=/root/.config/$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS \
    --export_stats=false \
    --receiver_ip=0.0.0.0 \
    --port=2575 \
    --api_addr_prefix=https://healthcare.googleapis.com:443/v1 \
    --logtostderr
```

Don't forget to put your credentials file inside your `~/.config` folder.

Here it worked fine. I hope helped you.

Cheers